# Why can't I import QtGui, QtWidgets, etc. on PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.6

This is my code, taken from an example in a book:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui

def window():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  w = QtGui.QWidget()
  b = QtGui.QLabel(w)
  b.setText('Hello World!')
  w.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 50)
  b.move(50, 20)
  w.setWindowTitle('PyQt')
  w.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/HackingGame/test file.py", line 2, in 
<module>

  from PyQt5 import QtGui

ImportError: DLL load failed: Unable to locate the specified function. unit.
```

I cannot import anything other than PyQt5. If I attempt to import anything more specific, such as QtGui, QtWidgets or anything in general, I get that error.

I'm using Python 3.6.2 (64-bit), PyQt5 (64-bit), On a Win7 (64-bit) machine.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Change `QtGui.some` to `QtWidgets.some`

Comment: And `from PyQt5 import QtGui` to from `PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets`

Comment: Also, the main problem is in the installation, you could explain how you installed pyqt5

Comment: I just googled 'pyqt5 download' and clicked on the first link, which downloaded a .exe file

Comment: What link do you mean?

Comment: This one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/PyQt5-5.6-gpl-Py3.5-Qt5.6.0-x64-2.exe/download

Comment: no thanks i found another way to do what i wanted